# Fql query event Venue Problem

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-fql

I am trying to query the venue instead of the location and I am having trouble doing so.
The events I am trying to display need the City and state instead of the "location" title.

Here is the code:

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=BSsec

down at the bottom you will see where I have tried calling the venue information.
all it ever returns is "array" which I have yet to figure out how to do.

Help is greatly appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do select venue.city, vanue.state
etc
you can check other venue fields here in docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

UPDATE:

```
SELECT venue.city,venue.street
FROM event
WHERE eid=156699104393395
```

hope this helps

Comment: Your answer is helpful but when i change it to venue.city is displays nothing =[

Comment: venue.city should be set when the event is created then it will be returned on query. Works for me, see: SELECT venue.city,venue.street FROM event WHERE eid=156699104393395